# Which select is faster in Sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

a is a table index, b is a normal column.

```
select a,b from ( select a,b from table where a in (*listA*) ) where b in (*listB*)
```

or

```
select a,b from table where (a=listA[0] and b=listB[0]) or (a=listA[1] and b=listB[1])...
```

I am using pseudocode to represent a list declaration.

Comment: These queries can give different results. You want to get the correct result, don't you?

Comment: Yea, I think i might have made a mistake writing them, I meant for them to give the same result. I meant the second one to select a and b at the end and basically for the first one i was trying to mimic the behaviour of the second but creating a temp table first of a select only using the index comparison and then selecting from the temp table using the non index column comparison

Answer (score 0):

The first query is wrong because it never looks at the combinations of `a` and `b`.

To use a temp table, you have to join with it:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM MyTable
JOIN (SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b UNION ALL
      SELECT 3,      4      UNION ALL
      SELECT 5,      6 ...)
USING (a, b)
```

Which version is better optimized depends on too many factors; the only way to find out is to measure with representative data.